# error Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath' when trying to use Ktor in android app

Tags: android, ktor

I'm trying to create local server on android app that can handle some complex JS Codes, I end up testing Ktor For creating the local server

```
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:2.3.9")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:2.3.9")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-features:2.3.9") 
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-compression:2.3.9")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-call-logging:2.3.9")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-status-pages:2.3.9")
```

and this is my server class

```
class KtorAppServer(private val context: Context, private val callback: ServerCallback, private val root: File?) {
interface ServerCallback {
    fun onStarted()
    fun onStopped()
    fun onError(message: String)
}
private lateinit var server: NettyApplicationEngine
init {
    startServer()
}
private fun startServer() {
    server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
        install(CallLogging) {
            level = org.slf4j.event.Level.INFO
            filter { call -> call.request.path().startsWith("/") }
        }
        install(Compression) {
            gzip()
        }
        install(StatusPages) {
            status(HttpStatusCode.NotFound) { call, status ->
                call.respondText(text = "404: Page Not Found", status = status)
            }
        }
        routing {
            staticFiles("/",root!!,"test.html")
        }
    }.apply {
        try {
            start(wait = false)
            Log.d("AppServer", "Server started on port 8080")
            callback.onStarted()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("AppServer", "Error starting server: ${e.message}")
            callback.onError(e.message ?: "Unknown error")
        }
    }
}
```

}

but I'm Unable to build the app having this error "Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'."
is it even possible to run Ktor server on android app ? the documentation is all about JVM

Comment: The `io.ktor:ktor-features:2.3.9` artifact doesn't exist.